# Frequency mean calculation for an arbitrary distibution in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, mean, frequency-analysis

I have a large dataset with values ranging from `1 to 25` with a resolution of `o.1` .  The distribution is arbitrary in nature with mode value of 1. The sample dataset can be like :

```
1,
1,
23.05,
19.57,
1,
1.56,
1,
23.53,
19.74,
7.07,
1,
22.85,
1,
1,
7.78,
16.89,
12.75,
15.32,
7.7,
14.26,
15.41,
1,
16.34,
8.57,
15,
14.97,
1.18,
14.15,
1.94,
14.61,
1,
15.49,
1,
9.18,
1.71,
1,
10.4,
```

How to evaluate the counts in different ranges (0-0.5,0.5-1, etc) and find out their frequency mean in pandas, Python.

expected output can be

values  ranges(f)   occurance(n)     f*n

```
 1  
 2.2      1-2   2   3
 2.8      2-3   3   7.5
 3.7      3-4   2   7
 5.5      4-5   1   4.5
 5.8      5-6   3   16.5
 4.3            
 2.7 sum-  11        38.5
 3.5            
 1.8        frequency mean  3.5
 5.9
```

Comment: What is expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) for binning, then convert `CategoricalIndex` to `IntervalIndex` for `mid` value, multiple column by `mul`, sum and last divide scalars:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[1,2.2,2.8,3.7,5.5,5.8,4.3,2.7,3.5,1.8,5.9]})
print (df)
    col
0   1.0
1   2.2
2   2.8
3   3.7
4   5.5
5   5.8
6   4.3
7   2.7
8   3.5
9   1.8
10  5.9
```

---

```
binned = pd.cut(df['col'], np.arange(1, 7), include_lowest=True)
df1 = df.groupby(binned).size().reset_index(name='val')
df1['mid'] = pd.IntervalIndex(df1['col']).mid
df1['mul'] = df1['val'].mul(df1['mid'])
print (df1)
            col  val     mid     mul
0  (0.999, 2.0]    2  1.4995   2.999
1    (2.0, 3.0]    3  2.5000   7.500
2    (3.0, 4.0]    2  3.5000   7.000
3    (4.0, 5.0]    1  4.5000   4.500
4    (5.0, 6.0]    3  5.5000  16.500

a = df1.sum()
print (a)
val    11.0000
mid    17.4995
mul    38.4990
dtype: float64

b = a['mul'] / a['val']
print (b)
3.49990909091
```

Comment: It gives the arithmetic mean a particular bean. My requirement is the frequency mean of the whole dataset. It is  :  [sum of (mid value of range* number of occurrence)  ]/ total number of occurrence.

Comment: @SANDIPANDAWN - Can you add expected output? Maybe is better if create only 10 rows sample for easy verify. Thanks.

Comment: @SANDIPANDAWN - Can you modify question, becaue bad format of comments?

Comment: I have modified the question to incorporate the demo output. Thanks @jezrael

Comment: suppose, there are 3 data in the range 2-3, which has a mid value of 2.5. So, we multiply 3 with 2.5(3*2.5=7 / 2*1.5=3) . In this way we can  add all the multiplication data and divide by the total number of occurrence in each range. That will give me the frequency mean of the dataset.  Thanks..

Comment: The edited answer is working fine and i wanted this only. Thanks @jezrael